# Plotting heat-map in python with multiple data sets

Tags: python, heatmap

I have a list FFT data which I want to plot in a single heat map. Each data set has its own X and Y. Usually I make use of Seaborn and Panda dataframe to plot the heatmap as the Frequency will be common for all the sets, but now the frequency column is unique for each data set. How can we plot a heatmap from this kind of data?

that is , I have a number of data sets as

X1,Y1

X2,Y2

X3,Y3

...

...

Xn,Yn

each X is unique and I want to plot these N graphs as a heatmap.

Comment: I like to use the seaborn heatmap with matplotlib.pyplot for a few of my visual heatmaps; I'll pivot my pandas dataframes to get the x and y I need, then plug it in It's Heatmap 1 here: https://blog.algorexhealth.com/2017/09/10-heatmaps-10-python-libraries/ And if you need more specifics on it: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused due to the fact that the Data was of non-uniform grid, now I created a common domain (x-axis value) for all the functions and then interpolated all the Data set to the new X-value.

I used the numpy.interpol() function to achieve this.